# memory leakage on asprintf using inside a loop in C

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a piece of code that looks like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    int number_of_chunks = 12;
    char *final_string = NULL;

    for(i = 0; i < number_of_chunks; i++) 
    {
        char *chunk = some_hash_table.pop(i);
        asprintf(&final_string, "%s%s", (final_string==NULL?"":final_string), chunk);
    }
    free(final_string);
    return 0;
}
```

Here I am concatinating string chunks dynamically,  meaning I don't know the size of each chunk in advance. For this I am using asprintf. The code works fine, however rise some serious memory issue. My doubt is asprintf allocates memory in each iteration and the code loses pointer in each iteration. If there is any other way I can concate string inside loop please guide me

Comment: Please consider giving feedback on downvote :)

Comment: Instead of using `asprintf`, measure `strlen(chunk)`, then use `realloc` and `strcat` or equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

To put your question in the simplest possible way, what you are essentially trying to do with the above code is 
1. Allocate memory to a pointer continuously(in your case 12 times in the for loop) and 
2. free it at the end only once, which is causing memory leak.

Like in the below code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    int number_of_chunks = 12;
    char *final_string = NULL;

    for(i = 0; i < number_of_chunks; i++) 
    {
        /*For example: similar to what asprintf does, allocate memory to the pointer*/
        final_string = malloc(1);
    }
    free(final_string);
    return 0;
}
```

From the above example it is easily visible that you have allocated the memory `12` times but freed only once.

code snippet:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{  
    int i;
    int number_of_chunks = 12;
    char *final_string = NULL;
    char *tmp = NULL;

    for(i = 0; i < number_of_chunks; i++)
    {
        char *chunk = some_hash_table.pop(i);
        asprintf(&final_string, "%s%s", (tmp==NULL?"":tmp), chunk);
        if (tmp)
            free(tmp);
        tmp = final_string;
    }

    printf("%s\n", final_string);
    free(final_string);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What if the number_of_chunks is of variable size?

Comment: @BibekSubedi: If you use C99 or later, you can use a VLA (variable length array) like `char str[n]`, where `n` is a variable.

Comment: @MOehm I am not using C99. Should i use double pointer and malloc it?

Comment: `(final_string==NULL?"":final_string)` is incorrect in this code, you pass `char **` to `%s`

Comment: But the solution with the string array leaves you with 12 separate strings, which is exactly what you had before. The idea is to concatenate these strings. You also need to initialise the strings to `NULL` somewhere. If you do that, the test `final_string[i] == NULL` is always true, so you could just `strdup` the chunk.

Comment: I believe the OP wants one single string, not an array of strings.

Comment: @SantoshA I think it is incorrect to give the same pointer for `%s` as you did give its address for the first argument : the function might allocate memory, updating `final_string[i]`, before it reads out for processing the `%s`.  However your code doesn't make sense anyway as each new chunk of text is supposed to append to the previous chunk.

Comment: @MOehm, M.M, Ludin. I have updated the answer, in which concatenation works fine with no memory leaks

Comment: @SantoshA when you free(tmp), the previous final_string address is not allocated anymore, isn't that a bug/thread unsafe code since your final_string content can eventually be overwritten by malloc, calloc, etc? It indeed solves the op question, but may not be used as a function or in multi-threaded applications.

Answer (score 0):

Others have already pointed out that you lose the reference to all but the last allocation and that having the same string that is written to as `printf` argument is probably undefined behaviour, even more so as re-allocations might occur and invalidate the format argument.

You don't use `asprintf`'s formatting capabilities, you use it only to concatenate strings, so you might want to take another approach. You could either collect the strings in an array, determine the needed length, allocate as appropriate and fill the allocated buffer with `memcpy`.

Or you could write a self-allocating string buffer similar to C++'s `std::stringstream`, for example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct append_t {
    char *str;          /* string */
    size_t len;         /* length of string */
    size_t size;        /* allocated size */
};

void append(struct append_t *app, const char *str)
{
    size_t len = strlen(str);

    while (app->len + len + 1 >= app->size) {
        app->size = app->size ? app->size * 2 : 0x100;
        app->str = realloc(app->str, app->size);
        /* error handling on NULL re-allocation */
    }

    strcpy(app->str + app->len, str);
    app->len += len;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct append_t app = {NULL};

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        append(&app, argv[i]);
    }

    if (app.str) puts(app.str);

    free(app.str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the rationale behind the realloc size? Wouldn't you rather always like to allocate [previous size] + x segments * y bytes, where y is a number suitable for the alignment requirements (like for example x*8 bytes)? Rather than logarithmically double the size each time.

Comment: The rationale is to reduce the number of allocations, at the cost of wasting some memory. The size isn't doubled _each time_, only when it's needed.

Comment: I realize that the purpose is to reduce the number of realloc calls. What I was trying to say is, why would you base the size of the memory allocations on the user data rather than the nature of the heap segments? I heard from some PC veteran at some point that when you write "STL-like" containers, you should pick a segment size x, suitable for the system, then grow that buffer size with some multiplier each time.

Comment: I have to admit that I haven't given that much thought for the example code. The initial chunk size and the multiplier are pulled from thin air.